# Send a notification every 15 minutes during the day

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification within 1 hour of the data I added to Firebase and I want to cancel the notification 1 day after adding the data. Because I don't know JavaScript, and I'm new to the software world yet, I couldn't quite figure out its algorithm, and I wrote something like that. The addedNewCard method works, but I couldn't adjust the time.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);

var newData;

exports.addedNewCard = 
functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Cards/{cardID}').onCreate(async 
(snapshot, context) => {

const cardID = context.params.cardID;

if (snapshot.empty) {
    console.log('No Devices');
    return;
}

newData = snapshot.data();

const cardAddedDate = newData.cardAddedDate;

const deviceIdTokens = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('DeviceToken')
    .get();

var tokens = [];

for (var token of deviceIdTokens.docs) {
    tokens.push(token.data().deviceToken);
}

var payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Tekrar vakti',
        body: 'Tekrar etmen gereken kelimeler var!!!',
        sound: 'default',
    },
    data: {
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATIoN_CLICK',
        sendCardID: cardID,
    }
};
const options = {
    priority: "high",
};

try {
    await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload, options);
    console.log('Notification sent successfully');
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
 })

exports.timeSettings = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 mins').onRun(async 
(context) => {
console.log(context.timestamp);

let now = new Date();

const finishWorking = now.setDate(now.getDate + 1);

const finishWorkingStamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(finishWorking);

db.collection('Users/{userID}/Cards').where('cardAddedDate', '<', 
finishWorkingStamp).get().then((snap) => {
    if (snap.exist) {
        snap.forEach(() => {
            return addedNewCard();
        }).catch((e) => {
            return console.log(e);
        });
    }
});

 })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "during the day"? Is it the opposite of night? If so, what are the time frame that you want for your scheduler?

Comment: For example user added a data and ı want to send notification for 24 hours when finish 1 day ı want to cancel to send notification

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your comment, I would recommend you to use [Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs). With Cloud Task you can delay an execution in the futur.

When a user send a data, you can plan the 24H notification in advance (with 1 notification every 15 minutes, for 1 day -> create 96 tasks, the next one with 15 minutes more in the delay than the previous one).

You have code sample [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#node.js). Have a look on this part, to change the delay

```
  if (inSeconds) {
    // The time when the task is scheduled to be attempted.
    task.scheduleTime = {
      seconds: inSeconds + Date.now() / 1000,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do the schedule notification in client side, instead, config and send schedule by server side. Try to create thread for client for processing the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a firebase cloud function where you need to upgrade your firebase account subscription and use pub-sub.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('*/15 * * * *').timeZone('Asia/Kolkata').onRun(async (context) => {
console.log('This will be run every 15 minutes');
return null});
```